box-shadows with html2canvas
I'm trying to use html2canvas library (version 1.4.1) with React 17 to download html as a picture and pdf. I think there is a problem with box-shadows.
Here is the code I use to download pictures and pdf:
const downloadChart = (divElement: HTMLElement) => {
        html2canvas(divElement)
        .then((canvas) => {
            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            if (chartId) {
                const link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = imgData;
                link.download = chartId + '.png';
                link.click();
            } else {
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
                const imgWidth = 210;
                const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 10, imgWidth, imgHeight);
                doc.save('charts-report.pdf');
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }

What am I doing wrong? is there a way to fix it? (I can't change the version of the library)
Or is there any better alternative? I tried even html-2-image but there seems to be other problems (like the download doesnt even start)

Do you know any good alternative which is completely working?
